# Select2 does not detect multiple attribute in my jquery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-select2, select2-rails

I am using the select2 gem in a rails app, I cannot get the form to accept multiple values in my `("id").select2()`

I would like it to detect the **multiple:true attribute** in **my jquery** and not in my select input but it doesn't work for me

for example:

this is my imput tags

```
= f.input :tag_ids, collection: [], input_html: { class: "js-example-basic-multiple js-example-responsive", id: "js-customer"}, include_blank: false
```

my jquery

```
 $("#js-customer").select2({
          maximumSelectionLength: 5,
          minimumInputLength: 1,
          multiple: true,
          tags: true,
          data: (#{Tag.order(:name).map{|tag| {id: tag.id, text: tag.name}}.to_json.html_safe}),
    });
```

What I am looking for is that I detect **the multiple:true** attribute in my **jquery**

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the multiple attribute to the input Tag:

```
<%= f.input :tag_ids, collection: [], input_html: { class: "js-example-basic-multiple js-example-responsive", id: "js-customer", multiple: true}, include_blank: false %>
```

Comment: It does not work for me, I would like to add it in the jquery because the multiple destroys my css style